# Node Express Router /users/:id vs /users/login

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I am building a restful api with a path /users/:id (for viewing a user's information) and /users/login (for logging in with credentials).
How do I prevent /users/:id only called when :id is a number? Is this even a good approach for building a restful api?

One way I could do it is I create a /users/:id route and inside I check if id is a number, otherwise switch between cases of login, signup, etc. Is this the right approach?

Answer (score 1):

> Just order routes based on the priorities

Now `user/login` will not execute search function

```
app.post('/user/login', login);
app.post('/user/signup', signup);
app.post('/user/:id', search);
```

Comment: There should be a slash in front of the bottom route: `app.post('/user/id', search);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `(\\d+)` expression:

```
const route = Router();

router.get('user/:id(\\d+)');
```